# Xamarin.iOS doesn't load dark theme

Tags: xamarin.ios, themes

I'm having some problems on loading my dark theme on Xamarin.iOS.
I followed these steps (including troubleshooting):
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/themes/dark/
It works fine in my Android project but doesn't load in my IOS version.
Here is the code of my AppDelegate:

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace T3.iOS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate :global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            var x = typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Themes.DarkThemeResources);
            x = typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Themes.iOS.UnderlineEffect);

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your info.plist.  The User Interface Style should say "Automatic."